# How to reset the printing system (CUPS)?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, printing, cups, etc

I would like to know how to cleanly reset the printing system (CUPS) to its initial state.

Alternatively, it may suffice for me to know how to take a "snapshot" of CUPS configuration and to roll back to it later.

This is to debug the following issue, which I could reproduce on several occasions on Linux Mint 21 and on Ubuntu 22.04.

After booting a freshly installed Linux Mint 21 or Ubuntu 22.04 and connecting the machine to my office LAN for the first time, network TOSHIBA e-STUDIO3015AC printers are automatically added to the list of printers as "driverless" and function properly.

However, after restarting the machine and after the printers get first removed, then added back to the list, the selection of 2-sided printing in the printing dialog is getting ignored. (The printing becomes one-sided unless changed in the printer options, but if printer option is set to two-sided, then one-sided printing does not work.) I noticed that the second time the automatically generated `/etc/cups/printers.conf` file contains many extra lines compared to the first time the printers were used, including this one:

```
Option sides one-sided
```

*This is basically a duplicate of [my question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1426753) on AskUbuntu.*

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. On one Linux Mint 21.2 computer, I was able to search for CUPS in the software manager, remove most of what I found (except for some with complex dependencies), delete lots of config files, reinstall, and printed worked like a charm again (until restart).
I tried to do the same thing on my other Linux Mint 21.2 computer, but somehow got it so it won't print at all, even after TimeShifting back to before I started messing with the printing.
My current workaround is to save files I need to print to a USB drive, shut down, boot into a live session, print, and then shut down and boot back using the hard drive itself.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/451244)